# Jupyter Notebooks: Updated packages don't update inside the notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I had an annoyance with some Pandas operations and someone suggested that upgrading it to the latest version might solve the problem.
I updated it from version 0.24.1 to 0.25.3

When I check the version in my virtual environment I get:

```
(matrix) ➜  web git:(T24_2019) pip freeze | grep pandas
pandas==0.25.3
```

But when I do the same thing inside the notebooks I get:

```
pandas==0.23.4
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I did restart the kernel many times, but it never worked.
Is there a specific way to restart it? Does it have anything to do with iPython having other versions of my packages installed?

Note: I do not use Anaconda.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have updated pandas in the same virtual environment as the one you are currently running your Jupyter Notebook with?

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince I'm not sure. I guess so. I ran the command above in my virtual env and I also started the notebooks in the same place, but how could I check that?

Comment: Have you tried running `!pip install --upgrade pandas` from within a cell of your current Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Not at all, but I just did it and it solved the issue (without the `!`)!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool then! Happy it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you check the versions of two different virtual environments. What you have to do is to upgrade the package of the virtualenv where your Jupyter Notebook is running.

As @The Half-Blood Prince already mentioned, you can do this by running the following command in a cell of your jupyter notebook:

!pip install --upgrade pandas